# Timer interrupt in C

Tags: c, interrupt, dos, dosbox

I have to write a c file which is about timer interrupt.Program will run on DosBox.
Features of program is simple :

> Program call a function(which is typed by me) for each timer interrupts.And these interrupts will be programmed with setvect and getvect functions.

For example It would be very nice if I have a c code which prints "Hello world\n" to screen once in a second without any sleep or delay function.I mean the code that print "hello world" must be in a function and for each interrupt program must call this function.

It is very hard to find example of this case,Can you forward any example link ? Thanks for all help..

Comment: Unless you make a protected-mode program you have to use the [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS).

Comment: It's been a while so I only remember the pain this kind of work caused, but [chapter 27](http://guideme.itgo.com/atozofc/ch27.pdf) of [this free book](http://guideme.itgo.com/atozofc/) talks about TSR's, and should contain most of the info you need.  Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PERIOD 999999
static sigset_t block ;
void timer_handler ();

static void init( ) __attribute__((constructor));
void init(){
    sigemptyset(&block);
    sigaddset(&block,SIGVTALRM);

struct sigaction act={0};
struct timeval interval;
struct itimerval period;

act.sa_handler=timer_handler;
assert(sigaction(SIGVTALRM,&act,NULL)==0);

interval.tv_sec=0;
interval.tv_usec=PERIOD;
period.it_interval=interval;
period.it_value=interval;
setitimer(ITIMER_VIRTUAL,&period,NULL);

    
}

void timer_handler(int sig){
write(1,"Hi\n",3); 


}
int main(){
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey omid, thanks for your answer! Please could you check out [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering any further questions, and amend this current answer accordingly. Enjoy your stay at SO!

Comment: Works beautifully! ...How do I stop it (programatically)?

Comment: /replies to self : same thing, just set the period to 0

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice.

In general, it is a good thing not to use function like print in interruption. In your case, because your code is simple it's not really a problem but you can have some priorities issues on more complexe programs if you spend to much time in interruptions...

Comment: The example above , is not necessary for me.I just want to see processes on an example code.My work is ofcourse more complex but firstly I have to analyse a code which calls a function typed by me for each time interrupt.Because I have not achieved this.